# Can we apply Quantum Superposition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition, schroedingers-cat

[Erwin Schrödinger’s famous thought experiment's video](http://www.physics4all.com/schrodingers-cat-sort-of-explained-by-perimeter-institute-physicists/)  presented by Perimeter Institute for Theoretical Physics. From this video can we conclude that in a macroscopic level we can not have a superposition. If we could have then, isn't it hard to comprehend that the cat is in both states and its a contradiction to our daily life?

Answer (score 1):

Quantum mechanics says there is a superposition. There is no reason to doubt QM on this point. The quantum processes of entanglement and decoherence make it impossible for us to be aware of the superposition. We will only be aware of one alternative, which fits well with our experience.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really get rid of the superposition. What happens is that the system gets entangled with the environment. This makes the system behave as if it were described by classical physics, but in reality it is still a quantum mechanical system and the superpositions are still there albeit hidden due to the entanglement with the environment.

If the cat is dead or alive with 50% probability and you have not yet observed the cat, then both possibilities are as real to you. Even though the state of the cat has decohered completely, without performing a measurement on either the cat or the environment (e.g. you can ask someone who has opened the box), there is no way for you to know which of the two states the cat is in. If we model you an intelligent machine and assume that your consciousness is represented by a bit string, then the state of this bit string does factor out of the global state, despite decoherence.

If this were not true and the bit string describing everything you are aware of would become correlated with the state of the cat, then you could guess which state the cat is in without performing any additional measurement and be correct in more than 50% of the guesses. So, this would mean that you have psychic abilities. But since no serious scientist believes in psychic abilities, we have to conclude that despite decoherence, the cat plus environment is in a superposition of the dead and alive state such that you factor out of this state, as long as no information about the cat has been communicated to you.

Of course, when you learn about the fate of the cat, the bit string describing everything you are aware of, goes into a superposition and the Many Worlds Interpretation of quantum mechanics then implies that there are then two Universes where you have learned about the two possible fates of the cats.

It's obviously not correct to say that that you are somehow aware of both fates, so even if the cat had not decohered that would still be true. One can interpret the superposition as the initial state as they are related to each other via the unitary time evolution operator. The superposition can be interpreted as the initial state expanded in a different basis. When you gain information you are considering a different "you", there are then two different versions of this in the global superposition.

Comment: "*If the cat is dead or alive with 50% probability...*"  What is the operator corresponding to the, apparently, two-state observable with allowed states "Alive" and "Dead"?

Comment: O = |Alive><Alive| - |Dead><Dead|

Answer (score 0):

Schroedinger's cat is one of the worst examples of scientific visualization. It is deceptive in that it pretends that a cat (on the time and temperature scale of the observer) can be treated as a quantum system. Moreover, it pretends that state superposition is an objective quantity of the quantum system, when, in reality, it's merely a statement about the observer's knowledge about the system. And on top of all of that it pretends that Schroedinger quantum mechanics naively applies to many-particle systems, when, in reality, it does not. A self-consistent theory of many-particle systems requires relativistic field theory, which, of course, trivially predicts that the cat is in thermodynamic equilibrium with a radiation field, which almost immediately breaks the pretended superposition of states.

Comment: The claim that `the state superposition is not an objective quantity of the system, but a statement about the observer's knowledge about the system` is itself subjective and interpretation-dependent.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: I really don't feel like getting into a discussion about this, but the failures of Schroedinger's cat have absolutely nothing to do with objectivity and subjectivity. Unlike the EPR experiment, or the twin paradox (both of which have been tested successfully in the lab), it can simply not be carried out in a way that would produce the required outcome for the paradox. A thought experiment that does not produce the required outcome is simply not a good thought experiment.

Comment: I agree that Schrödinger's cat is a horrible thought experiment for different reasons, but I would still be a bit careful about claiming that the quantum state only represents our knowledge of the system. See *on the reality of the quantum state* in [Nature](http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v8/n6/full/nphys2309.html) or on [Arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.3328)

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, I was traveling. As an experimentalist I don't think much of attempts to define "reality" in quantum physics (or any other type of theory). There are the things that one can measure and these are important to me. All experiments, so far, classical as well as quantum mechanical, prompt us to the realization that the whole state of the universe is not a measurable quantity. Therefor, from the viewpoint of a scientist who knows his limitations it seems rather unimportant to me to engage in a philosophical discussion about what "reality is" beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

The cat being in a superposition doesn't contradict everyday life. The cat interacts rapidly with the environment and the distinct versions of the cat can then no longer interact with one another. This process is called decoherence, see

http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2832.